# Local boundedness of weak solutions for a elliptic equation in divergence form

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, intuition, regularity-theory-of-pdes

[image]

[image]

How did the author find the test function $\varphi$?

Thanks

Comment: Since the title of the proof is "Approach by Moser", the author may have found that test function in some work by Moser.

Comment: The idea of proof is to show that the reverse Hölder inequality with the choice of this function implies an inequality of the type Caccioppoli. If i choose the function $\varphi =  \eta^{2}(\bar{u}_{m}\bar{u} - k^{2})$ what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'll discuss a possible line of reasoning that would lead one to construct the test function $\varphi$ used in the proof of Theorem 4.1.

First, Theorem 4.1 is an assertion about $u^+$, so it makes sense to choose a test function that vanishes on $\{u\leq 0\}$. Moreover, since the strategy of the proof of Theorem 4.1 is to iteratively improve the integrability of $u^+$, a reasonable choice for the test function is the product of a power of $u^+$ and a smooth cutoff function $\eta$:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test_function_first_try}
\tag{$*_1$}
 \varphi = \eta^2 v^{\beta + 1},
\end{equation}
where $v = u^+$ and $\beta \geq 0$. The reason for writing the exponent of $v$ as $\beta + 1$ will become apparent as the discussion progresses. The problem with this proposed test function is that $v^{\beta + 1}\not\in H^1(B_1)$ if $\beta> 0$. For example, if $\beta$ is large then it may be that $v^{\beta + 1}\not\in L^2(B_1)$. To guide our search for a satisfactory modification of this $\varphi$, let us recall the following lemma (it is one of the exercises in section 5.10 of Evans' book)

**Lemma** (Chain Rule).
Suppose $F\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $F'\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$. If $u\in H^1(B_1)$ then $F\circ u\in H^1(B_1)$ and $\nabla (F\circ u) = F'(u)\nabla u$.

For $F(t) = t^{\beta + 1}$, the derivative $F'(t)$ is unbounded as $t\to \infty$, so we seek a modification of the function $\varphi$ given in \eqref{eq:test_function_first_try} that will allow us to use the above lemma to deduce that $\varphi\in H^1(B_1)$. A reasonable approach for modifying $\varphi$ is to truncate $v$ from above in \eqref{eq:test_function_first_try} to obtain
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test_function_second_try}
\tag{$*_2$}
 \varphi 
 = \eta^2 \min\{m, v\}^{\beta + 1}
 = \eta^2 w_m^{\beta + 1},  
\end{equation}
where $w_m = \min\{m, v\}$. Because $F(t) = t^{\beta + 1}$ has bounded derivative on $[0, m]$, the chain rule guarantees that $w_m\in H^1(B_1)$. However, this approach will not allow the effective use of the ellipticity assumptions. To see this, note that for $\varphi$ as in \eqref{eq:test_function_second_try} we have
\begin{equation*}
 \nabla \varphi
 = (\beta + 1)\eta^2 w_m^\beta \nabla w_m + 2\eta w_m^{\beta + 1}\nabla \eta, 
\end{equation*}
so using the fact that $\nabla u = \nabla w_m$ on the support of $\nabla w_m$ we have
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:failed_use_of_ellipticity}
\begin{split}
 \langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla \varphi\rangle
 & = (\beta+ 1)\eta^2 w_m^\beta \langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla w_m\rangle + 2\eta w_m^{\beta + 1}\langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla \eta\rangle\\
 & = (\beta + 1)\eta^2w_m^\beta\langle A(x)\nabla w_m, \nabla w_m\rangle + 2\eta w_m^{\beta + 1}\langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla \eta\rangle\\
 & \geq \lambda(\beta + 1)\eta^2 w_m^\beta|\nabla w_m|^2 - 2\Lambda \eta w_m^{\beta + 1}|\nabla u||\nabla \eta|\\
 & \geq \left(\lambda(\beta + 1)|\nabla w_m|^2 - \Lambda \epsilon|\nabla u|^2\right)\eta^2 w_m^\beta - \frac{\Lambda}{\epsilon}w_m^{\beta + 2}|\nabla \eta|^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
for any $\epsilon>0$, where the final inequality was obtained by using $2ab \leq \epsilon a^2 + \epsilon^{-1}b^2$ with $a = \eta|\nabla u|$ and $b = w_m|\nabla \eta|$. The first term on the right-most side of this string of inequalities is undesirable because $|\nabla w_m|$ does not dominate $|\nabla u|$. In particular
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda(\beta + 1)|\nabla w_m|^2 - \Lambda\epsilon|\nabla u|^2
 \leq 0
 \qquad \text{ on }\{u\geq m\},
\end{equation*}
independently of how $\epsilon$ is chosen. In view of this computation, we return to \eqref{eq:test_function_second_try} to reconsider our choice of $\varphi$. Suppose that instead of truncating $v^{\beta + 1}$ as in \eqref{eq:test_function_second_try}, we only truncate part of $v^{\beta + 1}$ to obtain
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test_function_pre_third_try}
\tag{$*_3$}
 \varphi = \eta^2 w_m^a v^b, 
\end{equation}
where $a, b>0$ satisfy $a+ b = \beta + 1$. Note that \eqref{eq:test_function_first_try} corresponds to $a = 0$ and $b = \beta + 1$ and \eqref{eq:test_function_second_try} corresponds to $a = \beta + 1$ and $b = 0$. In order that $\varphi$ given in \eqref{eq:test_function_pre_third_try} be a valid test function we need $\nabla(w_m^av^b)|\in L^2(B_1)$. Using the fact that $v = w_m$ on the support of $\varphi$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \nabla(w_m^av^b)
 & = aw_m^{a - 1}v^b \nabla w_m + bw_m^a v^{b - 1}\nabla v\\
 & = aw_m^{\beta}\nabla w_m + bw_m^a v^{b - 1}\nabla v. 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Evidently first term on the right-most side of this equality satisfies $w_m^{\beta}\nabla w_m\in L^2(B_1)$. The second term will be in $L^2(B_1)$ provided one chooses $b = 1$ and thus $a = \beta$. With these choices of $a$ and $b$, the test function in \eqref{eq:test_function_pre_third_try} becomes
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:test_function_third_try}
\tag{$*_4$}
 \varphi = \eta^2 w_m^\beta v. 
\end{equation}
However, this creates another problem. Namely, if $0< \beta< 1$ then the function $G(t) = t^\beta$ has unbounded derivative near $t = 0$, so we cannot use the chain rule to deduce that $w_m^\beta\in H^1(B_1)$. To fix this, we shift $v$ up by a positive number $k>0$ and then adjust $\varphi$ so that we retain the property $\varphi \equiv 0$ on $\{u\leq 0\}$:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:correct_test_function}
\tag{$*_5$}
 \varphi 
 = \eta^2\left(v_m^{\beta}(v + k) - k^{\beta + 1}\right),  
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
 v_m = \min\{m + k, v+ k\}. 
\end{equation*}
Since $G(t)$ has bounded derivative on $t\in [k, m + k]$, we can apply the chain rule  to deduce that $v_m^\beta\in H^1(B_1)$. Moreover, since $v= v_m$ on the support of $\nabla v_m$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \nabla(v_m^\beta v)
 & = \beta v_m^{\beta - 1}v\nabla v_m + v_m^\beta \nabla v\\
 & = \beta v_m^\beta\nabla v_m + v_m^\beta \nabla v.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
From this equality and since $v_m\in H^1\cap L^\infty(B_1)$ we see that $v_m^\beta v\in H^1(B_1)$. It remains to determine how $k$ should be chosen. For this it is instructive to formally test the subsolution inequality:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:weak_subsolution}
\tag{sub soln}
 \int_{B_1}\left(\langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla \varphi\rangle + c(x)u\varphi\right)\; \mathrm d x \leq \int_{B_1}f\varphi \; \mathrm d x
\end{equation}
for all $0\leq \varphi\in H^1(B_1)$ against the test function \eqref{eq:test_function_first_try} (inequality \eqref{eq:weak_subsolution} is inequality ($*$) in the text that was posted by C'ezar). Even though such a computation is not valid, it will reveal that $k\geq \|f\|_q$ should be chosen and, once we have this property of $k$ we will agree not to tell anyone that this property was discovered from an incorrect computation. The incorrect computation follows. Let $\varphi$ be as in \eqref{eq:test_function_first_try} so that
\begin{equation*}
 \nabla \varphi
 = (\beta + 1)\eta^2 v^\beta \nabla v + 2\eta v^{\beta + 1}\nabla \eta. 
\end{equation*}
On the support of $\nabla\varphi$ we have $\nabla u = \nabla v$ so on this set,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \langle A(x)\nabla u, \nabla \varphi\rangle
 & = \langle A(x)\nabla v, \nabla \varphi\rangle\\
 & = (\beta + 1)\eta^2 v^\beta\langle A(x)\nabla v, \nabla v\rangle + 2\eta v^{\beta + 1}\langle A(x)\nabla v, \nabla \eta\rangle\\
 & \geq \lambda(\beta + 1)\eta^2v^\beta|\nabla v|^2 - 2\Lambda \eta v^{\beta + 1}|\nabla v||\nabla \eta|\\
 & \geq \frac{\lambda(\beta + 1)}{2}\eta^2 v^\beta |\nabla v|^2 - \frac{2\Lambda^2}{\lambda(\beta + 1)}v^{\beta + 2}|\nabla \eta|^2, 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where we used the inequality $2ab \leq \epsilon a^2 + \epsilon^{-1}b^2$ with $a = \eta|\nabla v|$, with $b = v|\nabla \eta|$ and with $\epsilon = \lambda(\beta + 1)/(2\Lambda)$. Using this estimate and the subsolution inequality \eqref{eq:weak_subsolution} gives
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 \frac{\lambda(\beta + 1)}{2}\int_{B_1}\eta^2 v^\beta |\nabla v|^2\; \mathrm d x
 & \leq \int_{B_1}(f - c(x)u)\varphi\; \mathrm d x + \frac{2\Lambda^2}{\lambda(\beta + 1)}\int_{B_1}v^{\beta + 2}|\nabla \eta|^2\; \mathrm d x\\
 & \leq \int_{B_1}(|f| + |c(x)||u|)\eta^2 v^{\beta + 1}\; \mathrm d x + \frac{2\Lambda^2}{\lambda(\beta + 1)}\int_{B_1}v^{\beta + 2}|\nabla \eta|^2\; \mathrm d x\\
 & = \int_{B_1}\left(\frac{|f|}{v} + |c(x)|\right)\eta^2 v^{\beta + 2}\; \mathrm d x + \frac{2\Lambda^2}{\lambda(\beta + 1)}\int_{B_1}v^{\beta + 2}|\nabla \eta|^2\; \mathrm d x, 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where, in the final inequality we used $|u| = v$ on the support of $v$. From the right-most side of this estimate we see that it will be convenient to choose $v\geq \|f\|_q$ and this observation motivates the choice
\begin{equation*}
 k=\begin{cases}
 \|f\|_q & \text{ if } f\not\equiv 0\\
 \text{arbitrary positive constant} & \text{ if }f\equiv 0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
in \eqref{eq:correct_test_function}. Choosing $k$ as such and then performing computations similar (but less technical) to those carried out in the proof of Theorem 4.1 in the posted question one obtains an inequality of the form
\begin{equation*}
 \|\eta v^{(\beta + 2)/2}\|_{2^*}^2
 \leq C\left(\|\eta v^{(\beta + 2)/2}\|_2^2 + \|v^{(\beta + 2)/2}|\nabla \eta|\|_2^2\right) 
\end{equation*}
which is precisely the kind of inequality that one can iterate to improve integrability of $v$. Although it was derived from an incorrect computation, this inequality suggests that a more careful computation (e.g. one starting with test function $\varphi$ as in \eqref{eq:correct_test_function}) may yield an inequality that can be used in practice to boost the integrability of $u^+$.